# Establishing order of the $\xi(s)$, the Riemann xi function

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, riemann-zeta, entire-functions

Clearly,

$$
\xi(s)=\frac{s(s-1)\pi^{\frac{-s}{2}}}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\zeta(s).
$$

Now from various literature, I understand that the order of the $\xi(s)=1$. The problem remains how to show it. The polynomials have the order of $0$, so I believe it is enough to show that the order of $\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)$ and $\zeta(s)$ is $1$ for each of the two? I am really struggling with this and I need to establish this for my dissertation.

I know there exists a formula:

An entire function $f$ is said to be of finite order if there exist numbers $a$,$r>0$ such that
$$|f(z)|\leq exp(|z|^a)$$
for all $|z|>r$. The infimum of all numbers $a$ for which this inequality holds is called the function order of $f$, denoted $\lambda=\lambda(f)$.

But I have no idea how to use this definition for the gamma or the zeta functions. Thank you for help

Comment: Is https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Completed_Riemann_Zeta_Function_has_Order_One any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ and $\xi$ is an entire function. By the integral representation for the $\zeta$ function over the half-plane $\text{Re}(s)>0$ it is clear that $\zeta(s)\ll e^{|s|}$. $s(s-1)$ has order $0$ and $\pi^{s/2}$ has order $1$. By the Weierstrass (or Euler's) product for the $\Gamma$ function, or just by Stirling's inequality, $\Gamma(s)\ll e^{|s|^{1+\varepsilon}}$ over $\text{Re}(s)>0$. It follows that the order of $\xi$ is $\leq 1$. By studying $\xi(s)$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$, it is straightforward to deduce that the order of $\xi$ is exactly $1$, since $\zeta(s)\to 1$ as $s\to +\infty$.

Comment: Ok, I like where this is going, but you never explicitly state the order of the Gamma. You only say  $\Gamma(s) << exp(|s|^{1=\epsilon}$. Could you please try and explain to me what does it mean exactly? I entered a territory of maths that I never studied before but it is too late to fall back now. Thank you.

Comment: @KuderaSebastian: we have to be careful in talking about *the order* of $\Gamma$ since $\Gamma$ is not an entire function, but anyway $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)}=\frac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi}$ and $\log\Gamma(n)\sim n\log n$ ensure that the order of $\xi$ is at most (and ultimately, exactly) $1$.

Comment: could you elaborate how the estimate for $\Gamma(s)$ can be derived from the Weierstrass product?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to Jack's idea above is through the Laurent series of the Riemann zeta function evaluated at $s=1$,

\begin{equation}
\zeta(s)=\frac1{s-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\gamma_n(s-1)^n
\end{equation}
where  each of the $\gamma_n$ are Stieltjes constants. Multiplying this by $s-1$ gives

\begin{equation}
(s-1)\zeta(s)=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\gamma_n(s-1)^{n+1}
\end{equation}

Now, examining the Theorem 2.2.2 of [*Entire Functions* by Ralph Philip Boas](http://books.google.de/books?id=MVk5jCQVuiYC&lpg=PP1&dq=Boas,%20Entire%20Functions&hl=de&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false) expresses the order $\mu$ of an entire function given by a power series

\begin{equation}
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n
\end{equation}

in terms of the coefficients:

\begin{equation}
\mu=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\log n}{\log (1/ \lvert a_n \rvert)}
\end{equation}
The [limit superior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_sequences) can be evaluated by [bounds found by Matsuoka](http://books.google.de/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&lpg=PA167&ots=K0jF87lv1b&dq=bounds%20Stieltjes%20constants&pg=PA167#v=onepage&q&f=false): that is, $\forall\, n\ge 10$,

\begin{equation}
\lvert\gamma_n \rvert \le\frac{\exp(n\log\log n)}{10000}
\end{equation}
and for infinitely many n

\begin{equation}
\lvert\gamma_n \rvert \gt\exp(n\log\log n-n\epsilon)
\end{equation}

By substituting [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_formula) for the factorial,

\begin{equation}
\log n!\sim n\log n -n\
\end{equation}

we can see that the limit superior is $1$: Then the upper bound on $\gamma_n$ dictates that this is eventually below $1+\delta$, and the lower bound dictates that it is also infinitely often above $1$.